# Graphene-Django Filenaming Conventions

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I'm rebuilding a former Django REST API project as a GraphQL one.  I now have queries & mutations working properly.

Most of my learning came from looking at existing Graphene-Django & Graphene-Python code samples.  There seem to be a lot of inconsistencies amongst them.

In some it was suggested that the GraphQL queries should be placed in `schema.py` whereas the mutations should be placed in `mutation.py`.

What I'm thinking makes more sense is to instead have these two files hold their respective code:
 - queries.py
 - mutations.py

I'm relatively new to Django & Python though so want to be sure that I'm not violating any conventions.

Interested in your thoughts!

Robert

Comment: If you feel that the below answer is the right one, please do accept it. It's a good practice in StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any conventions yet, since GraphQL is a [fairly new](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/) alternative method to REST. Thus, "conventions" are created at the moment we speak.

However, since `schema` is general-defined term you may rename it to `queries`.

This is my project structure:

```
django_proj/
    manage.py
    requirements.txt
    my_app/
        __init__.py
        migrations/
        admin.py
        schema/
            __init__.py
            schema.py     # holds the class Query. The GraphQL endpoints, if you like
            types.py      # holds the DjangoObjectType classes
            inputs.py     # holds the graphene.InputObjectType classes (for defining input to a query or mutation)
            mutations.py  # holds the mutations (what else?!)
```

So the `schema.py` (`__init__`) could be renamed to `queries.py` if you like. There is no much big difference between these two words.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Nik, especially your project structure.

Though, as an accomplished English language writer, I can't agree with you that there is little difference between "queries" and "schema".  :-)

Comment: Ha! See what you mean about the language. What I meant was that the convention leans towards to naming your main schema file as "schema" . But naming it as "queries" will not change much. If we were co-developers I would have absolutely no problem with that :)

Comment: This is great.  One more possible file: fields.py -- for fields shared between DjangoObjectType and graphene.InputObjectType classes.  If I was going to convert my current bloated schema field, I would need.

Comment: There's an active discussion on this right now on github here: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/545

Comment: That's great! One could actually see others project structure for inspiration. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I liked nik_m's answer so much I wrote some code to generate the template structure from inside the Django shell.  I want to enforce some consistency as I create these files over and over again.  I'm putting the code here in case someone else finds it useful.

```
import os

from django.conf import settings


def schema_setup(app_name):
    """
    Sets up a default schema file structure.
    """
    SCHEMA_DIRECTORY_NAME = 'schema'
    app_directory = os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_DIR, app_name)
    if not os.path.exists(app_directory):
        raise Exception("Can't find app directory {}".format(app_directory))

    schema_directory = os.path.join(app_directory, SCHEMA_DIRECTORY_NAME)
    if os.path.exists(schema_directory):
        raise Exception("Schema directory {} already exists.".format(schema_directory))

    os.makedirs(schema_directory)
    mutation_class = "{}Mutation".format(app_name.title())
    query_class = "{}Query".format(app_name.title())

    init_txt = "from .mutations import {}\nfrom .queries import {}\n".format(mutation_class, query_class)
    fields_txt = "# Insert common fields here.\nimport graphene\n"
    inputs_txt = "# Insert graphene.InputObjectType classes.\nimport graphene\n"
    mutations_txt = "# Insert graphql mutations here.\nimport graphene\n\nclass {}(graphene.AbstractType):\n    pass\n".format(mutation_class)
    queries_txt = "# Insert graphql queries here.\nimport graphene\n\nclass {}(graphene.AbstractType):\n    pass\n".format(query_class)
    types_txt = "# Insert DjangoObjectType classes here.\nimport graphene\nfrom graphene_django.types import DjangoObjectType\n"

    for fname, file_text in [("__init__.py", init_txt),
                             ("fields.py", fields_txt),
                             ("inputs.py", inputs_txt),
                             ("mutations.py", mutations_txt),
                             ("queries.py", queries_txt),
                             ("types.py", types_txt),
                             ]:
        with open(os.path.join(schema_directory, fname), "w") as output_file:
            output_file.write(file_text)
        print("Created {}".format(fname))
```

From inside the Django shell, run like `schema_setup("my_app")`

Note:

- This assumes you set `PROJECT_DIR` in your settings like `PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`
- In your top level schema, import like `from my_app.schema import MyAppQuery, MyAppMutation`
- I've gone back and forth on "query" vs. "queries" and "mutation" vs "mutations" -- as of this moment, the graphene documentation isn't consistent

Comment: Thank you for this, Mark.

Quick question: Do you know if it's possible to split the mutations & queries each into multiple files?

Comment: I'm splitting them up in my "master" schema file like "class Query(MyApp1Query, MyApp2Query, graphene.ObjectType):...", same pattern for "Mutations" class  which are then used like schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutations)