# graphql code organization for scalable projects

Tags: python, django, graphql, code-organization, graphene-python

Think that we have a big project with lots of apps which results in lots of queries and mutations. For such projects, how do you people handle the graphql code architecture. Let's take an example.

I have an app called accounts. It will have queries and mutation related to user and profile. The folder structure i am using is every app will have graphql folder which then will have schema.py and mutations.py. The code is arranged something like this for now

schema.py

```
class User(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        filter_fields = {
            'email': ['exact', ],
        }
        exclude_fields = ('password', 'is_superuser', )
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class ProfileNode(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class UserQuery(object):

    user = relay.Node.Field(User)
    users = DjangoFilterConnectionField(User)  # resolve_users is not needed now


class ProfileQuery(object):

    profile = relay.Node.Field(ProfileNode)
    profiles = DjangoFilterConnectionField(ProfileNode)


class UserProfile(ObjectType):

    profile = Field(ProfileNode)

    def resolve_profile(self, info, **kwargs):
        if id is not None and info.context.user.is_authenticated:
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user=info.context.user)
            return profile
        return None


class Viewer(ObjectType):

    user = Field(User)

    def resolve_user(self, info, **kwargs):
        if info.context.user.is_authenticated:
            return info.context.user
        return None
```

mutations.py

```
class Register(graphene.Mutation):
    """
    Mutation to register a user
    """
    class Arguments:

        first_name = graphene.String(required=True)
        last_name = graphene.String(required=True)
        email = graphene.String(required=True)
        password = graphene.String(required=True)
        password_repeat = graphene.String(required=True)

    success = graphene.Boolean()
    errors = graphene.List(graphene.String)

    def mutate(self, info, first_name, last_name, email, password, password_repeat):
        # console.log('info', info, first_name, last_name, email, password)
        if password == password_repeat:
            try:
                user = CustomUser.objects.create(
                    first_name=first_name,
                    last_name=last_name,
                    email=email,
                    is_active=False
                    )
                print ('user', user)
                user.set_password(password)
                user.save()
                if djoser_settings.get('SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL'):
                    send_activation_email(user, info.context)
                return Register(success=bool(user.id))
            # TODO: specify exception
            except Exception:
                errors = ["email", "Email already registered."]
                return Register(success=False, errors=errors)
        errors = ["password", "Passwords don't match."]
        return Register(success=False, errors=errors)
```

root schema

```
// just to show the number of mutations just for account apps.
from accounts.graphql.mutations import (
    Activate,
    DeleteAccount,
    Login,
    RefreshToken,
    Register,
    ResetPassword,
    ResetPasswordConfirm,
    )
from accounts.graphql.schema import Viewer, UserProfile


class Mutation(company_mutation.Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):

    activate = Activate.Field()
    debug = graphene.Field(DjangoDebug, name='__debug')


class Query(company_schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
    viewer = graphene.Field(Viewer)
    user_profile = graphene.Field(UserProfile)
    debug = graphene.Field(DjangoDebug, name='__debug')

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_viewer(self, info, **kwargs):
        if info.context.user.is_authenticated:
            return info.context.user
        return None

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_user_profile(self, info, **kwargs):
        if info.context.user.is_authenticated and id:
            return info.context.user
        return None


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

yo can see the mutations just for accounts app. There are many mutations and there will be more when considering all the apps. How you people are dealing with such?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226398/graphene-django-filenaming-conventions/46496989#46496989

Answer (score 0):

I think project organization based only on files like `schema.py`, `queries.py`, `mutations.py` is very bad for large project.

It's like organize your model parts, with files like `models.py`, `fields.py`, `utils.py` ...

Especially, a GraphQL ObjectType defined somewhere in your `queries.py` file can be returned or used as input by a mutation.

So I prefer a structure more based on objects and their logical relations

```
schema/
    __init__.py : contains your root schema actual code
    viewer.py : contains the ObjectType Viewer
    user/
        user.py : contains the ObjectType User and UserQuery
        profile.py : contains the ObjectType Profil
        account : contains the account management mutations
    login.py : contains the login / logout mutations
...
```

Note : you can embed mutations the same way you did queries, to be able to get mutations queries like :

```
mutation {
    account {
        delete(id: 12) {
            status
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please add some python code that shows how to organize mutations like that, please?